# Finding a woodshark sub model number

Tags: chainsaw

I have a Woodshark 1975, serial number starting with 02224D and with a display number 38CC EM. How do I find which variety of chainsaw I'm dealing with? I'm looking for a replacement bar, oil cap, gas cap, air filter if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you live in America. I've just done some quick Googling (which, perhaps, you also did). I think your chainsaw is made by Poulan, of the type Woodshark model number 1975. Is this correct?

Sears Parts Direct seems to offer chain saw parts [for sale](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/part-model/Poulan-Parts/Chainsaw-Parts/Model-1975LETYPE1/1324/1503220/P0803107/00001?blt=06&prst=&shdMod=). You can pick the right parts from their exploded-out diagrams.